# Django rest framework : Prevent one user from deleting/Editing/Viewing other users in ModelViewSet

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer, django-users

I was using Django users model for my Django rest framework. For this I used Django's ModelViewSet for my User class.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

**Serializers.py**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['id', 'username', 'password']

        extra_kwargs = {
            'password' : {
                'write_only':True,
                'required': True
            }
        }
    
    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
        Token.objects.create(user=user) # create token for the user
        return user
```

But currently from postman when I make the request using the token of one user to view, delete, edit other users

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/users/4/
```

Its able to edit/delete/view other users. I don't want that to happen and one user can make request on itself only is all I want.

This is my apps urls.py

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path, include
from .views import ArticleViewSet, UserViewSet
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter


router = DefaultRouter()
router.register('articles', ArticleViewSet, basename='articles')
router.register('users', UserViewSet, basename = 'users')


urlpatterns = [
    path('api/', include(router.urls)), 
]
```

How can I prevent one user from accessing other users when they make GET/POST/PUT/DELETE request.

**EDIT 1:** After adding the IsOwnerOfObject class as provided in he answers below, now when I am requesting the detail of the user himself, I am getting

> Authentication credentials were not provided.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Building from Ene's answer, authentication and permission classes needs to be provided.

Create a file named permissions.py.

```
from rest_framework import permissions

class IsOwnerOfObject(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return obj == request.user
```

next add the permission and authentication class to ModelViewSet:

```
from api.permissions import IsOwnerOfObject
from rest_framework.authentication import TokenAuthentication
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerOfObject]
    authentication_classes = (TokenAuthentication,)
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a file named `permissions.py`.

```
from rest_framework import permissions


class IsOwnerOfObject(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):

        return obj == request.user
```

next add the permission class to you ModelViewSet:

```
from yourapp.permissions import IsOwnerOfObject

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    permission_classes = [IsOwnerOfObject, <other permission classes you want to use>]
```

More info here:
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/4-authentication-and-permissions/#object-level-permissions

Comment: I believe `obj.owner` will give an error if he doesn't have that field on User. For this specific model he could just do `return obj == request.user`.

Comment: Yes, my bad, copy-paste mistake.

Comment: Tried the solution but now I am getting `Authentication credentials were not provided.` while making GET request. Check my EDIT in the question above

Comment: Found out, updated. I guess we need to provide authentication_classes again

Answer (score 2):

If you want to disable delete completely (Which is probably correct since if you want to "delete" a User you should deactivate it instead.) Then you can replace your view with this:

```py
from rest_framework import viewsets
from rest_framework import generics

class UserViewSet(
    generics.CreateModelMixin,
    generics.ListModelMixin,
    generics.RetrieveModelMixin,
    generics.UpdateModelMixin,
    generics.viewsets.GenericViewSet
):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
```

And then you can use **Ene Paul**'s answer to limit who can edit.

Comment: Tried Ene's answer I am getting `Authentication credentials were not provided.` while making GET request. Check my EDIT in the question above

Comment: Found out, updated

Answer (score 0):

Another all-in-one solution could be to use a queryset filter to directly narrow the queryset results. This will prevent an user to delete other users, but also prevent any unauthorized retrieving or listing as the only accessible data will be the user itself only.

```py
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    def get_queryset(self):
        """
        The get_queryset function is used to get the queryset of the user data corresponding to the logged in user.
        It is called when the view is instantiated, and it returns a list containing this user only.
        """
        # after get all products on DB it will be filtered by its owner and return the queryset
        owner_queryset = self.queryset.filter(username=self.request.user.username)
        return owner_queryset
```

And this can also be used with other objects to allow retrieving only data related to this user.